# Dependent selectbox in angular. Please suggest the solution

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="user_type" formControlName="userType">
        <option value="">...</option>
        <option value="sales">SALES</option>
        <option value="client">CLIENT</option>        
      </select>
```

hi this is my select box in angular website I want to show/enable another select box only if user select the option **sales** from above select box. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**AngularJS**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="user_type" formControlName="userType">
        <option value="">...</option>
        <option value="sales">SALES</option>
        <option value="client">CLIENT</option>        
      </select>

<select class="form-control" ng-if="user_type=='sales'" ng-model="test" formControlName="test1">
            <option value="">...</option>
            <option value="laptop">LAPTOP</option>       
          </select>
```

**Angular 2 or more**

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user_type" formControlName="userType">
            <option value="">...</option>
            <option value="sales">SALES</option>
            <option value="client">CLIENT</option>        
          </select>

    <select class="form-control" *ngIf="user_type=='sales'" [(ngModel)]="test" formControlName="test1">
                <option value="">...</option>
                <option value="laptop">LAPTOP</option>       
              </select>
```

I hope this may help you. If you have any doubts or suggestion let me know.

Comment: **Thanks a Lot...!!** Perfectly Worked.